# Python; calculate the average of three grades for each of a number of students

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to write code that will calculate the average of three grades for each of a number of students, and display a message depending on the resulting average grades.

The program needs to be able process any number of students; but each student will have only 3 grades. I have to use a method to calculate the average score for each student, and also to determine the appropriate message depending on the average.

This is the code I have so far and I am stuck:

```
def main():
    more = 'y'

    while more == 'y' and more == 'Y':
        numScore = int(input('How many test score per student: '))

    for numtest in range(numScore):
        print ("The score for test")
        score = int(input(': '))

        total += score

    total = 0

    print ("Student number", students + 1)
    print ('-----------------------------------------')

    avg = getAvg(numScore)

    if avg > 90:
        print ("You're doing excellent work")
    elif avg > 85 and avg <= 90:
        print("You are doing pretty good work")
    elif avg > 70 and avg <= 85:
        print ("You better get busy")
    else:
        print ("You need to get some help")

def getAvg (numScore):
    avg = total / numScore

    print ("The average for student number", student + 1, \ "is:", avg)

 more = input('Do you want to enter another student test score and get the average score of the student (Enter y for yes and n for no): ')

main()
```

Comment: calculates the average of three grades for each of a number of students and displays a message depending on the resulting average grade. The program needs to be able process any number of students; but each student will have only 3 grades.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to properly format your code, and ask an actual question, in the question body itself.

Comment: the condition "more == 'y' and more == 'Y' " can never be true since it requires "more" to simultaneously hold 2 different values.

Comment: I have to write a code that will:  calculates the average of three grades for each of a number of students and displays a message depending on the resulting average grade. The program needs to be able process any number of students; but each student will have only 3 grades. I have to use method to calculate the average score for each student, and also to deter the appropriate message depending on the average. This is the code I have so far and I am stock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had most of the elements correct in your script, but you need to think more about the order of everything.

Make sure you pass any arguments that are needed to a function. Your `getAvg` function needed three arguments for it to calculate the average and display it with the student number. Also you forgot to return `average`.

When calculating the `avg` ranges, if you first test for `>90`, then by definition the next `elif avg > 85` will be less than or equal to `90` so it is only necessary to then test for `>85`.

The following has been rearranged a bit to work:

```
def getAvg(student, total, numScore):
    average = total / numScore
    print ("The average for student number", student, "is:", average)
    return average

def main():
    student = 0
    more = 'y'

    while more == 'y':
        student += 1
        total = 0

        numScore = int(input('How many test scores per student: '))

        for test_number in range(numScore):
            print ("The score for test", test_number+1)
            score = int(input(': '))
            total += score

        print ("Student number", student)
        print ('-----------------------------------------')

        avg = getAvg(student, total, numScore)

        if avg > 90:
            print ("You're doing excellent work")
        elif avg > 85:
            print("You are doing pretty good work")
        elif avg > 70:
            print ("You better get busy")
        else:
            print ("You need to get some help")

        print()
        print('Do you want to enter another student test score and get the average score of the student?')
        more = input('Enter y for yes, and n for no: ').lower()

main()
```

Giving you the following kind of output:

```
How many test scores per student: 3
The score for test 1
: 93
The score for test 2
: 89
The score for test 3
: 73
Student number 1
-----------------------------------------
The average for student number 1 is: 85.0
You better get busy

Do you want to enter another student test score and get the average score of the student?
Enter y for yes, and n for no: n
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Comment: You are welcome. You can now click on the tick by the answer to accept it. You will also then earn a badge.